# PowerShelll: My manifested module gives warning when imported and need to accept with R to run it. How do not get that?

Tags: powershell

My test module is called ATest

The message I get when I import the module with 'Import-Module ATest -Force'

'Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the
Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run ..\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ATest\Os.psm1?'
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):

If I add psm1 files, I will get this for every one of them.

The module is located here.

tree /f ..WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\MODULES\ATEST
ATest.psd1
Os.psm1

When I type get-help for the only cmdlet in it, it works.  Get-Module list my module.

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---

Manifest   1.0.0      ATest                               Get-Os

So, it works, except the message that I need to hit R to let it load it.

The content of the ATest.psd1 file

```
@{
    RootModule = ''
    ModuleVersion = '1.0.0' # update the version in the csproj file as well
    PowerShellVersion = '5.1'
    GUID = '9b9a6212-3dbe-4f2d-9812-58efdaf704d1'
    
    NestedModules = @(
        "Os.psm1"
    )
    FunctionsToExport = @(
        "Get-Os"

    )
   
}
```

The content of the Os.psm1 file

```
function Get-Os{

    return [Environment]::OSVersion

}
```

Comment: Did you download the module from somewhere? If the answers below don’t solve your problem it might be because the module is blocked due to a “zone identifier” stored in an alternate data stream on the file - this tells Powershell that the file came from an “untrusted” location. To check, right click a module file and select “properties”. If the dialog shows an “unblock” checkbox the file is untrusted, which you can clear with ```Unblock-File``` per the warning message. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I made a mistake, try using

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ..\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\MODULES\ATEST -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

instead of

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: Ok thanks guys.   Initially I thought I needed to run this every time I copy new files.   But it looks like Unblock-File actually removes something from the file.   So, it's a onetime thing.   I can edit the files as much as I want. The below link also helped me as it talks about “zone identifier”  that mclayton mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Set your Execution Policy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: `Unrestricted` wouldn't help - you'd still get the prompt. While `Bypass` would help, deactivating execution policies _persistently_ is ill-advised.